# Expected area of intersection of set of special circles

Tags: probability, geometry

If we pick randomly three points $x_i, i=1,2,3 $ inside a circle of radius $R$, and we take all possible couples $\binom3 2$ of the intersection of two circles $B_k= \left(C(x_i,|x_i-x_j|)\cap C(x_j,|x_i-x_j|)\right) $ , $k=1,2,3$. Where in each couple, the two circles are centred at two points with radius equal to the distance between them. What is the expected area of the intersection of the three couples

$$\bigcap_{i\ne j}\left(C(x_i,|x_i-x_j|)\cap C(x_j,|x_i-x_j|)\right)$$
This is part of a problem which consist in determining the region where a device is.